# updating the set of fields in the marketing cloud

Tags: administration

in my marketing cloud had a field country.we given data like bl,NJ. But i want to change as Belgium,new jersey.like we have more records are their.so please help me,how to update.

Answer (score 1):

The limit on file attachments is 25MB. You could use chatter.
@Prakash, Please follow these helpful links:

- [Salesforce Developer Limits Quick Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_chatter.htm)
- [Chatter Files - A Better Option for Attaching Files to Records](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2012/04/chatter-files-a-better-option-for-attaching-files-to-records.html)

Comment: Even chatter files are limited to 50MB, no?

Comment: It is 2GB from the documentation @Adrian from this link and many others https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_chatter.htm. Let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: So you should **[edit]** your post to include more detail...

Comment: i wrote an vf page with to store an attachment with size 5.5 mb. it throws an view state exception exceds mor than 135KB.can u plase share the code in 2 ways 1.using the attachment taken as transient to upload and save the file

2.using jqury with ajax functionality to upload and save the file

Comment: Yes, transient on attachment body(of type blob) should help.